# fonts in Jupyter notebook has changed

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, jupyter-notebook

I noticed that the `markdown` fonts (titles, heading, body text, etc.) are all changed for me when I use chrome (but not in Firefox for instance). I suspecting it's something related to chrome since I had this issue in

- Windows as well as Linux,
- on my local notebook and a notebook that I open on github,
- on different (conda) environments with different jupyter installations.

This picture shows what I mean. Note that

- the scripts font is as before.
- The heading (here, Serie 2, exercise 4) is outlined,
- the body text is somewhat bolder than before.
- this is on git, not my computer even!

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that was due to a font named *helvetica neue* which I had installed on Windows and Linux. Don't know how and why it happened, yet by uninstalling the font everything went back to the default style.